# delete calendar event

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i want to delete event from calender when i delete cell from table view i add event like this

```
        eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKEvent *myEvent  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore]; 
myEvent.title     = [alertBodyField text];
myEvent.startDate = [theDatePicker date];
NSLog(@"%@",myEvent.startDate);
myEvent.endDate   = [theDatePicker date];
myEvent.allDay=NO;
[myEvent setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
NSError *err;
[eventStore saveEvent:myEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
if (err == noErr) {

}
```

but how i delete event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call [removeEvent:span:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/EKEventStore/removeEvent%3aspan%3aerror%3a) method for EKEventStore.

```
[eventStore removeEvent:myEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
```

Comment: i have 2 views in first view i hit calendar and add event then i switch to next view in which a tableview and many events over thr how the above method identify that the selected cell delete the particular event